# Write characteristic without prompt for pairing

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy

In my Android application, I am using BLE and have a read characteristic so that devices can read data from each other with no prompt. I added a write characteristic too now, but now the user is prompted to pair the devices. Is it possible to have a write characteristic without the prompt? I don't want to bother the user with it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When creating a Bluetooth Low Energy characteristic, there are two main things that you are in control of:-

- Property (readable, writeable, notifiable, etc).
- Permission (Open, encrypted, signed).

It appears that you are not setting the permission of the characteristic to open. If the characteristic that you are creating is using Android, then you can change this by:-

```
BluetoothGattCharacteristic.PROPERTY_WRITE
BluetoothGattCharacteristic.PERMISSION_WRITE
```

You can find more details about this here:-

- [BluetoothGattCharacteristic](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/BluetoothGattCharacteristic)
- [Example for Permission Write](https://www.programcreek.com/java-api-examples/?class=android.bluetooth.BluetoothGattCharacteristic&method=PERMISSION_WRITE)
- [Bluetooth Low Energy on Android, Part 2](https://www.bignerdranch.com/blog/bluetooth-low-energy-on-android-part-2/)

I hope this helps.

Comment: It was just that, I needed to make the permission to be open. I also had to restart my devices, they seemed to have been in a bad state, probably wasn't disposing something properly.